# Django- Updating data sent from a generic CBV? (Refreshing a view's variable)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to do the following:

```
class PurchaseCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = "generic_create.html"
    model = Purchase
    form_class = PurchaseForm
    try:
        latest_tag = Purchase.objects.latest('tag').tag
        print(latest_tag)
        next_tag = latest_tag + 1
    except:
        next_tag = 1
    initial = {'tag': next_tag}
```

The "tag" field should start with a value that is + 1 of the previous value that has been entered. When I test it out in the Django API, it works fine. However, when called from the view, it works correctly the first time, but seems to get "stuck" returning that first value, even when new objects are created which should update the value.

In fact, the try/except portion is never executed after the first page load, as the print order never shows up in the terminal, even with a hard browser refresh. How do I set this view to send an updated result every time the page is loaded?

Comment: Is the new `Purchase` correctly saved? If not, that could be the reason, why it's not updating properly. Also, you should probably define `get_initial()` - would be much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, the objects save correctly as i can successfully retrieve them in the API. In fact, if I wait long enough, eventually it will refresh. I think the issue is some sort of caching behavior in Django. I attempted to use `@never_cache` but it doesn't work with CBVs. I will look into the `get_initial()` and see if I can find anything there.

Comment: overriding get_initial solved the problem! Thanks for the tip

Comment: As you said, this is a *class* based view. You shouldn't be performing logic at the top level in a class; you do it in a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I moved the logic into the `get_initial()` method like so:

```
def get_initial(self):
    super(PurchaseCreate, self).get_initial()
    try:
        latest_tag = Purchase.objects.latest('tag').tag
        print(latest_tag)
        next_tag = latest_tag + 1
    except:
        next_tag = 1
    initial = {'tag': next_tag}
    return initial
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just make `tag` an [auto-incremented integer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield)?

Comment: Because I foolishly set it as the primary key on the model back when I was first learning to use Django. To change it now would be a huge headache. But, yes, that would be the best way to set this up.